# Fastest ubuntu image library for annotating

Tags: python, image-processing, imagemagick

I am currently working with images and would like to know the fastest image processing library regarding annotating. I'm currently using this command:

```
convert orig.tif -background Red -density 300 -font /usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/Arial.ttf -pointsize 12 -gravity south -splice 0x150 -gravity southwest -annotate +50+50 "left corner" -gravity southeast -annotate +50+50 'right corner' +repage endorsed.tif
```

I'm calling this within the subprocess.call method in python. If I do this in command line, I get around 1 second total time:

```
real    0m0.162s
user    0m0.940s
sys         0m0.030s
```

My program averages 1.96 seconds:

```
[**copied_from** avg] 0:00:00.071887
[**mysql** avg] 0:00:00.000265
[**cropped** avg] 0:00:00.433935
[**rm** avg] 0:00:00.007758
[**copied_to** avg] 0:00:00.147880
[**endorsed** avg] 0:00:01.963496
[**mssql** avg] 0:00:00.000010
```

I'm not sure why there's a discrepancy between calling it from command line or through python's subprocess.call(cmd,shell=True). Either way, both of these are too slow.

I'm basically cropping and annotating images. It seems that cropping is fast enough with imagemagick's convert, but annotating is too slow. Does anyone know of a faster image library? I'm comfortable using python/ruby, but at this point, any solution that is faster would be helpful.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2):

Calling things from `subprocess.call` is always going to have quite a bit of overhead compared to an actual shell (e.g. bash).

Have you tried using [imagemagick's python bindings](http://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/pythonmagickwand) instead of calling it through `subprocess`?  (Edit: Cancel that... Those bindings are rather outdated. I don't know of any better ones, though... I haven't used imagemagick through python in a long time...)

You could also do this with PIL, though it's a bit less flexible and probably not significantly faster.

For whatever it's worth, here's the equivalent to your imagemagick command using PIL.

```
import Image
import ImageDraw
import ImageFont

rect_height = 150

im_orig = Image.open('orig.tif')
width, height = im_orig.size
im = Image.new('RGB', (width, height+rect_height))
im.paste(im_orig, (0,0))

width, height = im.size
dpi = 300
im.info['dpi'] = (dpi, dpi)
font_size = 12
font = ImageFont.truetype('/usr/share/fonts/truetype/arial.ttf', 
                         int(dpi * font_size / 72.0))

draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
draw.rectangle([(0,height-rect_height), (width, height)], fill='red')

text = 'left corner'
text_width, text_height = font.getsize(text)
draw.text((50, height - 50 - text_height), 
    text, fill='black', font=font)

text = 'right corner'
text_width, text_height = font.getsize(text)
draw.text((width - 50 - text_width, height - 50 - text_height), 
        text, fill='black', font=font)

im.save('output.tif')
```

As you can see, it's a bit less convenient, but it does work. Also, this appears to be faster than imagemagick on my machine.  The above script takes ~0.43 sec for a largish image, while your equivalent imagemagick command (just run directly from the shell) takes ~1.1 sec.  Of course, imagemagick can do a *lot* more than PIL, but for simple image manipulation in python, PIL works pretty well.

(Edit: The speed difference is because PIL is saving the input tif (which is LZW compressed) as an uncompressed tif, while imagemagick saves it as an LZW compressed tiff, similar to the input.)

Comment: Joe,

Thanks for the fast response. I haven't used PythonMagick yet. I have used RMagick, the ruby bindings and found that the speeds were roughly the same.

Comment: Thanks so much for the insight. I'm going to try this in PIL. You're awesome.

Comment: Joe, I tried your code and it seems that the annotation works perfectly, and its much faster, 0.11 seconds on avg, but the original image is gunk and does not display properly. I'm using eog output.tif to view it. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: One other thing, the shell command I am using adds a strip that is height of 150 pixels to the image. So if the original was 100x100, the result image is 100x250. The above code doesn't seem to do that.

Comment: What type of compression do your tiffs have? PIL doesn't support as many types of compression as imagemagick does... It might be due to it incorrectly recognizing the type of compression the image has. Can you post an example image somewhere?

Comment: Ah! I misunderstood what the imagemagick command was doing!  I'll modify things to add the strip to the bottom, instead of overwriting the bottom 150 pixels.

Comment: @aznnico - Yeah, PIL doesn't handle that file well at all!  It looks like it's a packbits compressed tif, which PIL is supposed to be able to handle. Apparently, it doesn't handle it correctly.  This is definitely a fairly major bug, but PIL is not terribly well maintained these days (despite being _very_ widely used!).

Comment: @aznnico - Also, I modified the example to append the bar to the bottom, rather than overwriting the bottom 150 pixels. There may be a workaround for the bug... Let me look for a bit...

Comment: @Joe Kington - Have you ever tried VIPS? http://www.vips.ecs.soton.ac.uk/index.php?title=Speed_and_Memory_Use This looks promising.

Comment: Answering my own question: John, the maintainer of vips was kind enough to help me write the code using VIPS. VIPS IS SUPER FAST! You can find the solution here: http://libvips.blogspot.com/ Super fast imaging library with a python api ;)

Comment: Nice! I need to look into VIPS.  I hadn't heard of it before you mentioned it. It looks quite slick!